# how to run Valgrind with python process?

Tags: python, docker, valgrind

We have docker containers which use python services. We want to check for memory leaks in some of the python processes. We tried attaching valgrind with our python process after setting ENV variable PYTHONMALLOC=malloc in our docker file, but we are not able to get proper stack trace.

Command used:

```
/usr/bin/valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --trace-children=yes --track-origins=yes
```

Any idea what needs to be done to use valgrind with python process inside docker containers?

Comment: Python is a garbage-collected language. Python programs do not have memory leaks in the sense that Valgrind checks for.

Answer (score 0):

You need a python interpreter with debuginfo. That might be available as a separate package on your OS. Otherwise you will need to build a debug version of Python.

If you do this then Valgrind will detect errors in the *interpreter*, not in your Python script.